# complex sql query to update a table if an id is in

Tags: mysql

i would like to update massively a table regarding an other one. 
I have an commun id and i would like to update a row if the id is in the second table.

Table 1 :
ID_table1|is_in_db2

Table 2 :
ID_table2|ID_table1

I want to update is_in_db2 to 1 if the ID_table1 is in table 2

Comment: You sould do it in two parts : 1. Try to fetch `is_in_db2` from the table 1, and if there is any results, update table 2.

Comment: any possibility to do it with 1 query ? I have over 11 millions of rows

Comment: Have you looked at update join syntax? Are both tables indexed on table1 id?

Comment: yes, they are indexed on table1 id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to join the tables using an inner join on the ID.
This will update the specified column for any row that appears in both tables.

```
UPDATE
    table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID_table1
SET
    table1.is_in_db2 = 1;
```

Comment: Should probably be INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.id_table1

Comment: @P.Salmon Indeed. I've modified my answer, thank you.

Comment: perfect ! thks a lot